# Angular - in subscribe push element to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I am making angular application and where I have an empty arrays like these :

```
orders: Order[];
order_details: Product[];
```

Then i am making a service call in ngOnInit to store the data into orders array and order_details array,

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getOrders();
  }
```

This is the getOrders() function which is supposed to fetch every Order. Order object has an order_id, product_id list which has all the product ids of the products being ordered and order_time

```
getOrders() {
    this.order_service.getOrderList().subscribe({
      next: (data) => {
        this.orders = data;
        for (let order of this.orders) {
          for (let val of order.product_ids) {
            this.product_service.getProductById(val).subscribe({
              next: (data) => {this.order_details.push(data);}
            });
          }
        }
      },
    });
    console.log(this.order_details);
  }
```

getOrderList() uses api to return all orders

```
  getOrderList(): Observable<Order[]> {
    return this.http_client.get<Order[]>(`${this.baseURL}`);
  }
```

getProductById() uses api to return product by id

```
  getProductById(id: number): Observable<Product> {
    return this.http_client.get<Product>(`${this.baseURL}/${id}`);
  }
```

The Order object and Product object have fields like

```
export class Order{
    order_id: number;
    product_ids: number[];
    order_time: String;
}
```

```
export class Product{
    product_id: number;
    product_name: String;
    product_image: String;
    product_description: String;
    product_price: String;
}
```

I am trying so with the getOrders() function to fetch every order and from every order I access the product id array and find every product by id and then populate the order_details array with these products by using push()

So I was expecting a order_details array with products corresponding to the product_ids mentioned for every order in the orders array

However on doing so, error is being thrown and the order_details array is undefined

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')

Answer (score 1):

You have not initialized empty array.

```
order_details: Product[] = [];
```

You should enable strict mode in tsconfig.json. Strict mode prevents such errors at the compiler stage.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can edit

```js
this.product_service.getProductById(val).subscribe({
              next: (data) => {this.order_details.push(data);}
            });
```

to:

```js
this.product_service.getProductById(val).subscribe({
              next: (dataId) => {this.order_details.push(dataId);}
            });
```

Note: data --> dataId

2. You should initialize in your component order_details: Product[] = [];
3. You must check if(data) then push

Comment: the 2. part is valid, but what should the adjustments found in the code snippet change? You just renamed a variable.

Comment: Because two next: (data). Will lead to conflict

Comment: you must make sure you have data and data in the correct format

Comment: Thanks, Setting order_details: Product[] = []; seems to have worked

Comment: No, this will not lead to a conflict. Of course, it‘s not a good idea to have two different variables (different scope) with the same name, but it‘s definitely not leading to an error.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think you have another problem here, since I assume you want to have your `order_details` array to be in the same order as your `orders` array. The way your implementation works it is not guaranteed.

My suggestion is to do the following:

1. get rid of the `order_details` variable and adjust your `Product` class as following:

```
export class Order{
    order_id: number;
    product_ids: number[];
    order_time: String;
    details?: Product[];
}
```

2. Define orders as an Observable:

```
orders$: Observable<Order[]>;
```

3. Use `rxjs` operators to "enrich" your data in parallel HTTP requests (using `forkJoin`):

```
this.orders$ = this.order_service
      .getOrderList()
      .pipe(
        switchMap((orders) =>
          forkJoin(
            orders.map((order) =>
              forkJoin(
                order.product_ids.map((product_id) =>
                  this.product_service.getProductById(product_id)
                )
              ).pipe(map((products) => ({ ...order, details: products })))
            )
          )
        )
      );
```

This will lead to the `order` objects `details` property to be "enriched" with the data coming from `this.product_service.getProductById(product_id)`.

4. Use `async` pipe to listen to the output of `orders$` observable.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is just from not initializing your arrays:

```js
orders: Order[] = [];
order_details: Product[] = [];
```

Note that your current setup will not maintain the order that product details were requested, they will randomly be pushed to the array as soon as a request completes.

Suggestions below.

---

Simple Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2kfwbz?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Optimized Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2whd3b?file=src/app/app.component.html

Before subscribing to observables, you should create a pipeline that transforms the data as necessary.

`orders` is just the result of `this.order_service.getOrderList()` so we can initialize it as such. Some people tend to annotate observables with a `$`.

```
export class MyComponent {
  orders$: Observable<Order[]> = this.order_service.getOrderList();

  constructor(
    private order_service: OrderService,
    private product_service: ProductService
  ) {}
}
```

`order_details` depends on the result of `orders$` so you can create a pipeline with that as the starting point.

```js
order_details$: Observable<Product[]> = this.orders$.pipe(
    switchMap((orders) => {
      const res: Observable<Product>[] = [];
      for (let o of orders) {
        for (let id of o.product_ids) {
          res.push(this.product_service.getProductById(id));
        }
      }
      return forkJoin(res);
    })
  );
```

Note the use of `switchMap` and `forkJoin`.

`forkJoin` takes an array of observables, waits for all of them to complete, then emits an array with the completed values. Note they do need to *complete*, if you are using long lived observables, you can use `combineLatest` instead.

`switchMap` is necessary since `forkJoin` returns an observable, and `pipe` also returns an observable. This would create a nested observable if we were just using `map`. `switchMap` resolves the inner observable.

To display the values in html you can use the async pipe, which automatically subscribes / unsubscribes. It's generally best practice, but not always realistic.

```html
<h1>Orders</h1>
<pre>{{ orders$ | async | json }}</pre>
<h1>Order Details</h1>
<pre>{{ order_details$ | async | json }}</pre>
```

---

Note that this isn't optimized since both observables are making a duplicate request for `orders$`. But it is nice and simple.

To eliminate the duplicate, you can save the result of orders, and then after it has been populated, create the pipeline for `order_details`

```js
  orders: Order[] = [];
  order_details$: Observable<Product[]> = new Observable();

  ngOnInit() {
    this.order_service.getOrderList().subscribe((res) => {
      this.orders = res;
      this.getOrderDetails();
    });
  }

  getOrderDetails() {
    const res: Observable<Product>[] = [];
    for (let o of this.orders) {
      for (let id of o.product_ids) {
        res.push(this.product_service.getProductById(id));
      }
    }
    this.order_details$ = forkJoin(res);
  }
```

```html
<h1>Orders</h1>
<pre>{{ orders | json }}</pre>
<h1>Order Details</h1>
<pre>{{ order_details$ | async | json }}</pre>
```

Of course you can subscribe and save the result to a local variable if you want.

```js
order_details: Product[] = [];

getOrderDetails() {
    const res: Observable<Product>[] = [];
    for (let o of this.orders) {
      for (let id of o.product_ids) {
        res.push(this.product_service.getProductById(id));
      }
    }
    forkJoin(res).subscribe((res) => this.order_details = res)
  }
```

**Note: I'm assuming these observables are the result of simple http requests, so unsubscribing is unnecessary**

Comment: This is actually similar to my answer. Quick note: if you don‘t wand to have 2 single requests to the orders endpoint, you can just use `shareReplay` operator.